# Windows 10 keeps freezing randomly

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, freeze

My Windows 10 freezes randomly, there is no any sound or anything. It doesn't work unless I restart PC (I have tried to wait 10-15 minutes to see if it starts working but it doesn't).

I'm not entirely sure but I think the problem started after I switched SATA hard drive to SSD (now I have both, OS is on SSD).

I'm using following:

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte B150M-DS3H-CF
Hard drive: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB
```

I have tried most common tips ([for example this one](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/72971-add-ahci-link-power-management-power-options-windows.html))

Also I have tried to check the windows error log, there is nothing in it related to it.

**Is there any software or anyway that can capture this error so I know what is causing that error?**

Comment: You can force a blue screen dump https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard that can be analysed. You can use this to analyse https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26798 or to monitor.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the numlock key work while its in the frozen state? if not, the kernel is locked and it will not come back.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that the SSD has some read errors which causes the OS to freeze.

Make sure the SATA cable is well connected, you can also try another cable.

This has happened to me and it proved to be a defective SATA cable (or perhaps one of the connectors).